# Ember default template doesn't show up

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to emberjs it's  really cool, I've follow this [guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ga99hMi7wfY) in the official website
, After I add some Posts model fixture, the default `application` template refuses to show up, I can't figure out where's the problem.

Here's my [code](https://github.com/markson/ember-tutorial-learning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really nice that ember has errors information in the console output, in my case, it shows

`Error: assertion failed: The route posts was not found`

I forgot add the `/post` router, then after I added
    App.Router.map ->
        this.resource('about')
        this.resource('posts')

everything get back to work!

Answer (score 0):

- You refer to `scripts/app.js` but the file you have there is `scripts/main.js`
- You need to create an Ember.Application, like: `window.App = Ember.Application.create();`
- You need to [define routes](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) for `posts` and `about`, otherwise Ember will throw an error for the `{{#linkTo}}` helpers.